# Jquery validate textarea validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am pretty new to jquery validate so there is hopefully a simple answer to my problem!

I got a form with a textarea and i want to do a simple validation (required). The validation works fine for the simple text fields but it does not work for the text area...
I got the following code to initialize jq validate.

note hat my textarea has the both the id and name attributes set to "post_content".

```
            /**
             * 
             */
            this.account_validator = $("form#profile_form").validate({
                rules: {
                    post_content : "required",
                    errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
                        if (element.is("textarea")) {
                            label.insertAfter(element.next());
                        } else {
                            $(element).closest('div').append(label);
                        }
                }
                }
            });
```

If my "post_content" is ==""and I add the following alert popup I get the following

```
alert(this.account_validator.form()); --> true
alert(this.account_validator.element("#post_content")); --> false
alert(this.account_validator.form()); --> true
```

As far as I understand the .element method on the validator object should add that element for validation so the second call to the form() method should also return false...

BTW, if my "post_content" is !="" and I add the following alert popup I get the following

```
alert(this.account_validator.form()); --> true
alert(this.account_validator.element("#post_content")); --> true
alert(this.account_validator.form()); --> true
```

Thanks,

Christian